# Why is R diff function slow?

Tags: r, diff, benchmarking

When working with vectors in R, the `diff` function computes the differences between each value and the previous one. From `?diff`:

> If `x` is a vector of length `n` and `differences = 1`, then the computed result is equal to the successive differences `x[(1+lag):n] - x[1:(n-lag)]`

However, when I tested the execution time of `diff` function vs their theoretical expression (using `microbenchmark` function from `microbenchmark` package), the `diff` function is slower. Here is my code:

```
library(microbenchmark)

mb.diff1 <- function(n, seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  vec <- runif(n)
  out <- diff(vec)
  return(out)
}

mb.diff2 <- function(n, seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  vec <- runif(n)
  out <- vec[2:n]-vec[1:(n-1)]
  return(out)
}

times.diff1 <- c()  
times.diff2 <- c()
vec.sizes <- c(1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4)
for (n in vec.sizes){
  bench <- microbenchmark(
    mb.diff1(n,1),
    mb.diff2(n,1))
  times.median <- aggregate(
    bench$time,
    by  = list(bench$expr), 
    FUN = median)
  times.diff1 <- c(times.diff1, times.median[1,2])
  times.diff2 <- c(times.diff2, times.median[2,2])
}

perf.ratio <- times.diff1/times.diff2
names(perf.ratio) <- vec.sizes
print(perf.ratio)
```

I finished with vec.sizes of 1e4, so the excution time for you guys does not take too long but I make them go until 1e7. You can see the results here:

[image]

As you can see, the `diff` function is slower for all vector sizes. The quotient tends to decrease because it seems in both cases the execution time is a linear function of the vector size so we can't say that `diff` performs better as n increases. So here comes the questions:

1. (The obvious question) Am I doing something wrong in my code when measuring the execution times?
2. What could be the cause of the `diff` function being slower than their theoretical expression?
3. Do you know a most efficient way to compute the differences vector than `x[(1+lag):n] - x[1:(n-lag)]`?

I'm using R 3.1.2 in Linux.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: R-3.1.2 is over 2 years old.  Your timings include generating a random vector, so you're not isolating the difference you ask about.  Using simplified functions that only call `diff` and `vec[]`, `diff` is faster on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine running R-3.3.2.  `diff` is also generic, so there's some cost to method dispatch.  Calling `diff.default` directly (not generally recommended) is faster.

Comment: Also `diff.default` converts its input to matrix and does some checking. https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/diff.R

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaUlrich, I updated my Ubuntu to 16.04 and installed R 3.3.2. I also took the call to runif outside the functions so I could measure the real execution time of our diff functions. Whit all that, diff performs a little better for vectors larger than 1e4. I suppose the better performance of vec[ ] for small sizes is due to the checking. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to help expand and illustrate the points I made in my comment.

```
library(microbenchmark)

mb.diff2 <- compiler::cmpfun(function(vec) {
  n <- length(vec)
  vec[2:n]-vec[1:(n-1L)]
})

times.diff1 <- c()  
times.diff2 <- c()
times.diff3 <- c()
vec.sizes <- c(1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4, 1e5)

for (n in vec.sizes) {
  set.seed(21)
  vec <- runif(n)
  bench <- microbenchmark(diff(vec), mb.diff2(vec), diff.default(vec))
  times.median <- aggregate(bench$time, by = list(bench$expr), FUN = median)
  times.diff1 <- c(times.diff1, times.median[1,2])
  times.diff2 <- c(times.diff2, times.median[2,2])
  times.diff3 <- c(times.diff3, times.median[3,2])
}

setNames(times.diff1/times.diff2, vec.sizes)
setNames(times.diff1/times.diff3, vec.sizes)
```

First, you'll notice that I compiled the `mb.diff2` function.  This is because `diff` and `diff.default` are byte-compiled.  I also put the calculation of `n` inside `mb.diff2`, since calculating the vector length should be part of the measured function call.

Here are the results of the timings, along with my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R> setNames(times.diff1/times.diff2, vec.sizes)
       10       100      1000     10000     1e+05 
3.5781536 2.3330988 1.2488135 0.9011312 0.9660411 
R> setNames(times.diff1/times.diff3, vec.sizes)
       10       100      1000     10000     1e+05 
1.5945010 1.4609283 1.1021190 1.0034623 0.9987618 
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] microbenchmark_1.4-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.9      digest_0.6.8     MASS_7.3-45      grid_3.3.2      
 [5] plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0    
 [9] ggplot2_1.0.1    stringi_0.4-1    reshape2_1.4.1   proto_0.3-10    
[13] tools_3.3.2      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    compiler_3.3.2  
[17] colorspace_1.2-6
```